# SAS Comparing values in groups

Tags: sas

In the following table I'm trying to create Switch_from_start :

**start_ind**: I created this value to secure when name = "Start" as the first item within the same ID after sorted in descending order.

```
Data df;
  set df;
if name = "Start" then start_ind = 1;
run;

proc sort data = df; by ID Name descending start_id; run; 
/*In the table below Name is not sorted*/
```

**switch_from_start**: any change in Value in comparing to the Value when name = "Start" within the same ID. So if a different Value within the same ID occurs, switch_from_start will be "yes" + start_value + later appeared Value that is different than the start Value. (refer to output example below)

[image]

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Please post your example output data as plain text within your question, not as an image.

Comment: Will your groups ever contain more than two distinct values ?

Comment: @Richard no it’s already de-duped :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are applying a 'value computed over the group' to the first row in the group.  This kind of data processing flow can be accomplished with a DOW loop for computation over the group followed by a serial loop over the group for application and output.  The tracking of first occurring distinct values in the group can be tracked in a variety of ways including a maximally sized temporary array, a dynamically sized hash, or a delimited concatenation.

Example using delimited concatenation:

`findw` is used to check for a value previously concatenated (this is the tracking). The delimiters are underscore (`_`) which is your separator, **and** space () for the trailing spaces of the concatenation

`do` … `until` is the DOW loop and `do` … `to _n_` is the serial loop.  Notice how the computed value is cleared after being `output` in the first row of each group.

```
data have;
  do id = 1 to 10;
    do _n_ = 1 to 20 * ranuni(123);
      length name $20;
      if _n_ = 1 
        then name = 'Start';
        else name = scan ('apple pear guava peach orange cherry lemon lime', ceil(8*ranuni(123)));

      value = ceil(6*ranuni(123));
      if id = 5 then 
        value = 1;

      output;
    end;
  end;
run;

data want;
  do _n_ = 1 by 1 until (last.id);
    set have;
    by id;

    length group_computation $75;

    if not findw (group_computation, strip(value), '_ ') then
      group_computation = catx('_', group_computation, value);
  end;

  if index(group_computation, '_') = 0
    then group_computation = 'no';
    else group_computation = 'Yes, ' || group_computation;

  do _n_ = 1 to _n_;
    set have;
    output;
    if _n_ = 1 then group_computation = '';
  end;    
run;
```